# What are the advantages of using an hash table to store methods inside a class?

Tags: compiler-construction, interpreter, bytecode, compiler-optimization, vm-implementation

I am developing a language and a virtual machine. Language is class based, dynamically typed and it is static scoped.

A sample class looks like:

```
class Foo
{
    var bar
    {
       function get { return bar; }
       function set(value) { bar = value; }
    }

    function f1() {...}
    function f2() {...}
}
```

Instance variables declared inside a class are protected and can be accessed by setter/getter functions. Functions declared inside a class are publics.

At runtime instance variables can be stored in an array, so in this example bar will be stored at index 0 of that array and the compiler will be responsible to generate correct LOAD 0 instruction in its getter function.

What about the other functions? Using an array to store functions will certainly result in faster runtime access than using an hash table but I wondering what could be the drawbacks. I mean what if I would like to support the ability to add functions to a class at runtime? What about overriding?

What are the advantages of using an hash table to store methods instead of a regular array?

Comment: If it's dynamically typed, how does the compiler know which index is the right one for a given member name? For example if there is a second class with members `foo`, `bar`, `baz` then does `obj.bar` somewhere else in the code correspond to `LOAD 0` or to `LOAD 1`?

Comment: Don’t mix up the terms. First you have to decide whether your solution is array/list (read: index) based or map (read: name) based. Only if you decide for map based, you may think about whether the map has to be *hash* based. After all, there are more mapping algorithms than hashing and for the typical number of functions in an object, hashing is not necessarily the most efficient choice.

Answer (score 0):

If the language is dynamically typed, then you will need the ability to look up a method/member function by name.

You can use an array that contains names and links to procedures, you can use a tree, you can use a linked list, you can use a hash, or you can use some other data structure, but you must store both the name of the procedure and a link to the procedure so that you can look it up by name.

Hash tables tend to be more efficient for large numbers entries, but for small numbers of entries you sometimes spend more time hashing the name on every lookup than you would spend just scanning an array.

So, to answer you question, hash tables would have the advantage that method lookup times would not tend to grow when people put large numbers of methods (100's, 1,000's) into one class.

Hash tables would have the disadvantage that they might make method lookup times longer for classes with small numbers of methods (less than a few dozen, as a guess).